# Ошибка TypeError: Candle() takes no arguments при создании экземпляра класса Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, классы

Текст ошибки:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\Python\Tasks\main.py", line 14, in <module>
        pig = Candle(5, "White candle")
    TypeError: Candle() takes no arguments
```

Код:

```
  class Candle():
        def __int__(self, mgl_time, model="unknown", glow_time=0):
            self.model = model
            self.mgl_time = mgl_time
            self.glow_time = glow_time
            """if glow_time == 0:
                self.glow_time = mgl_time
            else:
                self.glow_time = glow_time"""
        def burn(self, time=1):
            self.glow_time -= time
            print(str(self.glow_time + time) + "c. ---> " + str(self.glow_time) + "c.")
    # ошибка в этом месте
    pig = Candle(5, "White candle")
    print(pig)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправьте опечатку в конструкторе класса: вместо  `def __int__` должно быть `def __init__`